# Kotlin EventBus triggered twice

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I use this code for eventBus in kotlin, but it triggers twice. I don't know why this happens

```
object EventBus {
    val bus: BroadcastChannel<Any> = BroadcastChannel<Any>(1)

    private val parentJob = Job()
    private val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = parentJob + Dispatchers.Default

    private val scope = CoroutineScope(coroutineContext)
    fun send(o: Any) {
        scope.launch {
            bus.send(o)
        }
    }

    inline fun <reified T> asChannel(): ReceiveChannel<T> {
        return bus.openSubscription().filter { it is T }.map { it as T }
    }
}
```

and use it in this way

```
EventBus.send(NetEvent(false))
```

and listen t it as below (this code runs twice)

```
 var subscription = EventBus.asChannel<NetEvent>()
    var s = scope.launch {
        subscription.consumeEach { event ->

            Timber.i("NetEvent ${event.isConected}")
            currentNet = event.isConected
        }
    }
```

Comment: it'll help you :https://gist.github.com/takahirom/f2dbcc3053adfd87ac7e321d95a23021

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would prefer [MutableSharedFlow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-mutable-shared-flow/):

```
class EventBus {
    private val events = MutableSharedFlow<Any>()

    suspend fun dispatch(event: Any) {
        events.emit(event)
    }

    suspend fun on(coroutineScope: CoroutineScope, handler: suspend (Any) -> Unit) =
        coroutineScope.launch(start = CoroutineStart.UNDISPATCHED) {
            events.asSharedFlow().collect { event -> handler(event) }
        }
}

class EventBusTest {
    @Test
    fun testEventBus() {
        val events = ConcurrentLinkedDeque<String>()
        runBlocking {
            val eventBus = EventBus()

            val job1 = eventBus.on(this) { events.add("1: $it") }
            eventBus.dispatch("a")

            val job2 = eventBus.on(this) { events.add("2: $it") }
            eventBus.dispatch("b")

            job1.cancelAndJoin()

            eventBus.dispatch("c")

            job2.cancelAndJoin()
        }
        assertEquals(listOf("1: a", "1: b", "2: b", "2: c"), events.toList())
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It solved my problem